# Create a new database on SQL Server on Linux using sqlcmd

Tags: sql-server, linux, windows, sqlcmd

i'm new in SQL Server and i don't know what happened. i need to create a database,how i can do it?

[image]

i have problems

[image]

Why the > is show me?

Comment: Try using the `GO` statement. I'd suggest having a read of the `sqlcmd` documentation. SO isn't a website for asking for tutorials.

Comment: Are you definitely using the latest drivers? (ODBC 13.1 iirc).

Comment: Please state the commands and the errors. The text cannot be copied/pasted by others, and the text cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add GO as the batch separator. Nothing will get executed untill you add it e.g.

```
> CREATE DATABASE TESTDB
> GO
```

The MS docs are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-linux-2017

Comment: 1> CREATE DATABASE prueba
2> go
SqlState 24000, Invalid cursor state
1> CREATE DATABASE prueba
2> go
SqlState 24000, Invalid cursor state
1> CREATE DATABASE prueba go
2> CREATE DATABASE prueba
3> go
SqlState 24000, Invalid cursor state

Comment: are you adding the '>' in, i only included that to show separate lines. Its should just be your create statement on one line and then GO on the next

Comment: it could possibly be down to open connection. disconnect every session and then try again

Answer (score -1):

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P yourpassword

CREATE DATABASE database
GO

USE database
GO
```

Comment: 1> SELECT Name from sys.Databases
2> GO
SqlState 24000, Invalid cursor state